Operation is not valid due to current state of object when calling Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
I have an Uno Platform project, TargetFrameworks;$(DotNetVersion)" is ;net7.0-windows10.0.1901;net7.0; I am trying to implement cross platform local storage using the APIs from the Windows.Storage namespace. In the code:
public static async Task<T?> RetrieveDataAsync<T>(string filename)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
    {            
        try
        {
            StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile storageFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync($"{filename}.json");
            string serializedData = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(serializedData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}

I am getting the message "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object" on the line "...ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder". When I try build against the windows platform.  The Uno Documentation says it is supported across all platforms. What is causing this?

Found the issue, it was an error on my part that took me a long time to notice.  I was debugging an unpackaged build of my app.
My Uno project when I attempted to debug the windows solution, the drop down immediately to the right gave me a number of options. They were MyProject.Windows(Unpackaged), MyProject.windows(Packaged), and MyProject.Windows(WSL). I was getting the error when, I tried to debug the MyProject.Windows(Unpackaged) option. Fixed it when I switched to the MyProject.Windows(Packaged) option.
